# Grep exact string's from xml file

Tags: bash

how could I grep exact word's(strings) from xml file. This is the part of xml file (input file):

```
 <Sector sectorNumber="1">
    <Cell cellNumber="1" cellIdentity="42901" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />
    <Cell cellNumber="2" cellIdentity="42905" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />
  </Sector>
  <Sector sectorNumber="2">
    <Cell cellNumber="1" cellIdentity="42902" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />
    <Cell cellNumber="2" cellIdentity="42906" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />
  </Sector>
  <Sector sectorNumber="3">
    <Cell cellNumber="1" cellIdentity="42903" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />
    <Cell cellNumber="2" cellIdentity="42907" cellRange="35000" numberOfTxBranches="1" hsCodeResourceId="0" />   
  </Sector>
```

I want to grep all `cellIdentity="..."`, so bascily it should look like this

```
cellIdentity="42901"
cellIdentity="42905"
cellIdentity="42902"
cellIdentity="42906"
cellIdentity="42903"
cellIdentity="42907"
```

when I tried with `grep -E "cellIdentity=" input.xml` I get whole sentence (line), but I need only as above...

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse structured data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-o` option of `grep` to  get only the matched pattern. With your example in a file named `t.txt`:

```
grep -o 'cellIdentity="[0-9]*"' t.txt 
cellIdentity="42901"
cellIdentity="42905"
cellIdentity="42902"
cellIdentity="42906"
cellIdentity="42903"
cellIdentity="42907"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Jordan@workstation:~$ egrep -o "cellIdentity=\"[0-9]{5}\"" ddff 
cellIdentity="42901"
cellIdentity="42905"
cellIdentity="42902"
cellIdentity="42906"
cellIdentity="42903"
cellIdentity="42907"
```

`-o` only outputs the matching string, and not the entire line.

`[0-9]{5}` is looking for exactly 5 occurrences of digit.

Rest of the answer contains expected :)

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation of the `-o` flag and the structure of the regex. Adding those would change this from giving an answer into teaching how one goes about solving this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this regular expression:

```
grep -oP 'cellIdentity="\d*"' file
```

Comment: Just a heads-up: `-P` (to support Perl-compatible regexes) is not available on all platforms (e.g, OSX).

Answer (score 1):

To extract data from XML files, use XML tools:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//Cell" -m @cellIdentity -v . -n file.xml
```

This is far less fragile and handles way more XML files and edge cases than grep.

Comment: Just to clarify: [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) is not a standard utility. OSX users: the standard `xmllint` utility could be used: `xmllint --xpath '//Cell/@cellIdentity' file.xml | sed 's/^ //; s/ /\'$'\n''/g'`